# how to create Mongodb ID in subdocument in laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

how to create Mongodb ID in subdocument in `laravel 5.2` with `jenssegers` ??

Declaration syntax :

```
$arr["_id"] = new MongoId;
```

> Error shown on browser: App\Http\Controllers\MongoId not found

Answer (score 1):

You're in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace while `MongoId` is defined in a global one so you need to:

```
$arr["_id"] = new \MongoId();
```

or add

```
use MongoId;
```

at the top of file.

Comment: thanks bro for the response but i am still facing the same problem

Comment: have you changed all occurences of `MongoId`? If `mongo` extension is available then there's no way `new \MongoId()` could not work

Comment: yes mongo extension is available i am even quering from mongo and i am getting result

Comment: Then you're still constructing `MongoId` in a wrong way somewhere in your code

Comment: Then can you paste a copy of right syntax for laravel using jensenger

Comment: If it happens that you're using jensenger with NEW driver `mongodb` (and not `mongo` as I asked), you need to use its syntax: `new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id);`